# Post request is not established when prompt box is submitted

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Whenever I run this code, no post request is sent, it just shows me a blank page with no `alert();`. Basically what I want is when user loads the page, a prompt box appears, and when user puts a PW in the box, it sends a post request

Thank you in advanced!

```
<?php // mac.php

$password = 'crVL5Hi/hjE/E';
if(isset($_POST['password'])) {
if($_POST['password'] == NULL) {
die('empty');
} else {
if(crypt($_POST['password'], 'cryptsalt') == $password) {
die('success');
} else {
die('fail');
}
}
}

?>
<span id="page"></span>
<script>
var pw = prompt("Please enter a password.","");
if(pw != "") {
  $.post("mac.php",
  {
    password:pw
  },
  function(data){
    alert(data);
  });

} else {
while(pw == "") {
var pw = prompt("Password was left blank.","");
}
}

</script>
```

Thanks!

EDIT:
Thanks for pointing out something obvious, it works now.

Thanks again. ;)

Comment: And... is there a file called `mac.php`?

Comment: Yes that's the same file.

Comment: If the user enters a blank password first, a request will never be sent, even if they enter it later.

Comment: What does your developer console have to say? Are there any errors thrown part-way into execution? Can you see the XHR being sent and then not returning appropriately?

Comment: Here, you can try it here - https://v1k.org/personal/mac.php

Comment: Yup, forgot that. Included it and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @user2055695 Now it's posting to Google. Please use the actual URL.

Comment: What do you mean? Look here - https://v1k.org/personal/mac.php it won't send the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$` is not defined — include jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

You have not included Jquery.. Please Include it..

ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: try to download it then try..because jquery is still not able to include..see error on your console

Comment: Is there any way to check of the user clicked cancel on the prompt. I am using safari on iOS.